# i installed iredmail on my ubuntu desktop 14.04 but why is it i cant access the emails on another pc

Tags: mail, mail-server

I installed ired mail but I can only access the web mail app using my own computer but if I try to access it in another computer is saying server not found on the web page

Answer (score 1):

I think that your firewall is blocking it. Try running `sudo ufw disable` to disable the firewall.